Why does my fputc call continue to cause a segmentation fault?
I am trying to create a program that creates a new file and copies the content on of existing file to it. I am able to open read and write the contents of the original file to memory but when it comes time to write the contents of memory to the new file a segmentation fault occurs.
section .data
openFile:    db 'file1.txt', 0       ; Source file to open for reading
fileModeR:   db 'r', 0               ; File mode for reading
writeFile:   db 'file2.txt', 0       ; Destination file to open for writing
fileModeW:   db 'w', 0               ; File mode for writing

section .bss
fileHandleR  resd 1                  ; To store the file descriptor for reading
fileHandleW  resd 1                  ; To store the file descriptor for writing
buffer       resb 1                  ; Reserve buffer for one character

section .text
extern fopen, fgetc, fputc, fclose
global main

main:
    ; Open source file for reading
    push fileModeR                    ; Push read mode
    push openFile                     ; Push file name
    call fopen
    add esp, 8
    mov [fileHandleR], eax            ; Store the file handle
    test eax, eax                     ; Check for null
    jz exit_program                  ; Exit if fopen failed

    ; Open destination file for writing
    push fileModeW                    ; Push write mode
    push writeFile                    ; Push file name
    call fopen
    add esp, 8
    mov [fileHandleW], eax            ; Store the file handle
    test eax, eax                     ; Check for null
    jz close_source                  ; Close source file and exit if fopen failed

    ; Read from file1.txt and write to file2.txt
copy_loop:
    mov eax, [fileHandleR]            ; Load the file pointer into eax
    push eax                          ; Push the file pointer onto the stack
    call fgetc                        ; Read a character
    add esp, 4                        ; Clean up the stack after the call
    test eax, eax                     ; Test for EOF or error
    js close_files                    ; If sign flag is set, hit EOF or error

    mov ecx, eax                      ; Move the character into ecx to use later with fputc
    mov eax, [fileHandleW]            ; Move file handle for writing into eaxn
    push ecx                          ; Push the character to write
    push eax                          ; Push the file handle for writing
    call fputc                        ; Write the character
    add esp, 8                        ; Clean up the stack

    test eax, eax                     ; Test for fputc success
    js close_files                    ; If sign flag is set, an error occurred

    jmp copy_loop                     ; Repeat the loop

close_files:
    mov eax, [fileHandleW]            ; Get the file handle for writing
    push eax                          ; Push it to fclose
    call fclose                       ; Close file2.txt
    add esp, 4                        ; Clean up the stack

close_source:
    mov eax, [fileHandleR]            ; Get the file handle for reading
    push eax                          ; Push it to fclose
    call fclose                       ; Close file1.txt
    add esp, 4                        ; Clean up the stack

exit_program:
    ; Exit the program
    mov eax, 1                        ; syscall number for exit
    xor ebx, ebx                      ; return 0 status
    int 0x80                          ; call kernel

The error is occurring at the call fputc and I believe the segmentation fault is occurring during the fputc call suggesting that the file handle (which should be a FILE* pointer) is not being recognized correctly by fputc. I am new to assembly and I cannot figure out why it is doing this. I have attached the screenshot of my gdb and I can see everything seems to be working up till fputc such as ecx containing the right value and eax containing the file handler
GDB Output

fputc takes first the character and then the FILE* so they should be pushed in reverse order. Here you seem to be pushing them in the same order. Switch pushing eax and ecx the other way?

The fputc wants the character as the first argument and the FILE* as second. This means they should be pushed in the opposite order (since that’s how stack works, last one is taken out first.
Therefore you should first push EAX and then ECX so they are read in the correct order.

Worked immediately! Thank you so much for your help!
